# Why adding salt to kneading make it wetter?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, water, ions, food-chemistry

Last week I tried a new recipe of pizza dough:

- 65mL of Water;
- 140g of Wheat Flour (typo 3);
- 7g of Yeast;
- 1 big spoon of Olive Oil;
- 25g of cooked potatoes;
- 1g of common salt;

I think the recipe uses cooked potatoes as direct source of strach for Yeast. I have mixed all ingredients and kneaded 20 minutes until having a homogeneous dough that is not sticky. Then I added salt (about 0.5g) to the dough and I mixed it. Then the dough became wetter and stickier, I had to add flour in order to recover from the previous state.

It was an amazing experience, because it is somehow unexpected and counter intuitive. **Adding salt to preparation seems to lead to more free water in dough.**

I have the feeling that water is bound into macro-structure and adding salt may release some water in exchange of ion caging.

Anyway I would like to deeper explain this phenomenon. I am looking for concrete, scientific and reliable explanation.

**Update**
I read comments about osmosis phenomenon but I do not think it is the good explanation, it happens but does not explain the final state. Osmotic pressure is a transient phenomenon and really need a system boundary to be defined (after all this is a Fick force applying over a surface). I agree that a gradient exists at the beginning, and when mixing but it does not explain why afterwards there is more free water in the whole system. I also agree that there are local gradient, because of macro structure (proteins, etc.) but I am not asking about the transient phenomenon, I am asking about the overall equilibrium.

I express the question in another way:
Why adding salt to a finite mass of dough (of fixed recipe) releases some water and force us to add flour to keep dough constancy as before?

Comment: [Osmosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmosis).

Comment: @DHMO have you read the question, your comment was really fast (quite instantaneous)? Anyway, could you develop what you mean by osmosis in this particular case (where are boundaries and how fluxes are defined), and make an answer then I could accept it if relevant.

Comment: The wheat proteins trap water. You're pulling out that water via osmosis by adding more salt.

Comment: I doubt it's just the proteins. Starch is a polymeric sugar, and the salt ions are too big (hydrate shell) to freely diffuse into them. So, they create an osmotic pressure.

Comment: updated question

Comment: maybe the salt killed the yeast and made it excrete it's water content

Comment: @Riftcaster nice idea, just for information the process is really quick, about 10 seconds, do you think it holds?